# Delete Border on Accordion UI

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

I want to put the **border** propriety of the accordion plugin on "**NONE**", but I don't find  the code which is responsible of doing that.

Thanks :)

there is a screenshot :
[image: My example]

I want to set the yellow border on "border:none".
And I have another problem, which is that when I select one of the radio buttons I can't change my choice and select another one, like if other ones are disabled.
Have you Any Idea ?
Thks :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        // Accordion
        $("#accordion").accordion({
          autoHeight: false,
          navigation: true,
          header: "h3" });
      });
    </script>


    <form id="accordion" action="commande_chequier_succes.html" method="post">


      <div class="prelevement_auto">
        <h3 class="prelevement_auto_p">
          <input type="radio" name="paiement" /><strong>Prélèvement automatique</strong>
        </h3>
        <div class="target1">
          <p class="xx">J'autorise le prélèvement sur mon compte bancaire :<br/><strong>XXXXXXX  XXXXXXX  XXXX  XX</strong></p>
          <p>
            <input class="target_submit" name="prelevement_auto_submit" type="submit" value="COMMANDER" />
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="cesu">
        <h3 class="cesu_p">
          <input type="radio" name="paiement" /><strong>CESU</strong>
        </h3>
        <div class="target3">
          <p>
            <strong>Frais de traitement 3.90 euros</strong><br/>Pour des raisons de sécurité, nous vous demandons de nous retourner vos CESU uniquement
              par Lettre Recommandée Avec Accusé de Réception (LRAR) à l'adresse suivante :<br/><br/>
              France Ménage 128 rue de la Boétie 75008 Paris<br/><br/>
              N'oubliez pas de cocher la case assurance R3 dans votre LRAR qui vous permettra de vous faire rembourser vos CESU à hauteur de 458 euros maximum.
          </p>
          <input class="target_submit" type="submit" name="cesu_submit" value="COMMANDER" />
        </div>
      </div>


    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following style to your page and the border will not appear.

```
<style>
h3 {
  outline:none;
}
</style>
```

To fix the radio buttons issue, add `event: "mouseup"` to your accordion JavaScript function.

See [**Working jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/Ev8rw/)

Comment: Please What about the radio buttons which are disabled when one of them is selected ??

Comment: Add `event: "mouseup"` to the accordion function to fix up the radio button issue. See my edited answer and jsFiddle demo.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code generated by the plugin. From http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ theming tab:

> **Sample markup with jQuery UI CSS Framework classes**

```
<div class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset">
  <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-active ui-corner-top">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"/>
    <a href="#">Section 1</a>
  </h3>
  <div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active">
        Section 1 content
  </div>
  <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"/>
    <a href="#">Section 2</a>
  </h3>
  <div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
    Section 2 content
  </div>
  <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"/>
    <a href="#">Section 3</a>
  </h3>
  <div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
    Section 3 content
  </div>
</div>
```

This will give you the classes for the elements you want to style.

Comment: It'll be easier to figure out whats going on if you can post your code of the relevant sections. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this at the bottom of your css file:

```
h3.prelevement_auto_p {border:0px;}
```

or

```
h3.ui-accordion-header {border:0px;}
```

If that doesn't work, try inline styling:

```
<form id="accordion" ....>
   <h3 class="prelevement_auto_p" style="border:0px;">...</h3>
```

I don't think you must use radio buttons in the heading - the heading has to be used only for showing a title and for opening and closing accordion elements when clicked.